# How to patch object file in static library / how to extract object file that has full path within archive

Tags: ida

I am trying to extract an object file (.obj) from a Windows static (.lib) library so I can patch it in IDA, then rearchive it back into the library.  I am doing this because IDA won't allow me to patch a static library containing multiple object files.

I am trying to use the ar that comes with mingw.  The file I am looking to extract has a full path (e.g. "E:/some/path/to/filename.obj" - the forward slashes are correct).  I can see this file as listed when I run `ar -t library.lib`.  However, when I run `ar -x library.lib E:/some/path/to/filename.obj` I get an error "no entry E:/some/path/to/filename.obj in archive".

What am I doing wrong please?   Or can I apply a patch to an object file within a static library using IDA directly?